# Not able to change the case of a folder name through API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Through the Microsoft Graph it is not possible to change the case of a folder name through API. For example if we have a folder with name "abc" and I have to change it to "ABC". It can be done directly from the SharePoint, but it didn't work when I try to do it using the following endpoint:

**Request:**

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "name": "ABC"
}
```

**Response:**

```
Status Code: 200 OK
request-id: f1368c43-d1b6-46c5-af9b-7d879eb2ae1e
```

This is returning with **200**("OK") status-code. But at SharePoint side it is not changing the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the comparison is case-insensitive. Since there isn't a clear change, it says "sure, looks good" but since it doesn't see anything changed, it isn't committing it.

The workaround is to use a temporary name as an interim step. So first you change "abc.txt" to "rename-abc.txt" and then to "ABC.txt". This will force the API to recognize changes to the `name` property and ensure they're committed properly.

Comment: Yes, the workaround will work here. But it required an extra call that I wants to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation (and bug really) of the Microsoft Graph API.

However, if you use `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/` as your endpoint instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`, you will get the correct "case preserving" behavior expected during renames.